# Showing $C_{x}+C_{y}=C_{x+y}$ where $C_{x}=\left\{ p\in\mathbb{Q}:p<x\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Define $C_{x}=\left\{ p\in\mathbb{Q}:p<x\right\}$ for any real number $x$. I want to show that $C_{x}+C_{y}=C_{x+y}$ for all real $x$ and $y$. I was easily able to show that the LHS is a subset of RHS, but I wasn't sure about the other direction. I'm having trouble showing that if a rational $q$ is less than $x+y$, then $q=a+b$ for rational $a$ and $b$ with $a<x$ and $b<y$. I'm guessing it will involve the use of the density of the rationals, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You might want to think about splitting into cases. I'm going to outline some ideas assuming $x,y\geq 0$ for ease. If $x\leq y$ and then $q<x$ you're done. However, if $q<y$ but $q\geq x$ it's not too difficult to think of $a,b$. If $q\geq y$ then maybe consider $b<y$ and close to $y$ and show that $q-b < x$ so you can take that as $a$.

Comment: Note that the density is essential, if you use $\mathbb Z$ instead of $\mathbb Q$ for instance then $1$ is the max element of $C_2$ so the max element of $C_2+C_2$ is $2$ yet $3\in C_{2+2}$ is not reachable.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to find some element of $C_x+C_y$ which is greater than $q$, but still smaller than $x+y$.

Let $q\in C_{x+y}$. Then $q\lt x+y$, so let $\epsilon=(x+y)-q$. Now, we know that there exists a rational $a$ such that $x-\frac{\epsilon}{4}\lt a\lt x$, and a rational $b$ such that $y-\frac{\epsilon}{4}\lt b\lt y$. (This step uses the density of the rationals.) Let us consider $a+b$.

We clearly have
$$ (x+y) - \frac{\epsilon}{2} \lt a+b \lt x+y.$$
So first, we know that $a+b\in C_{x+y}$. Second, we know that $q = (x+y)-\epsilon \lt x+y - \frac{\epsilon}{2}\lt a+b$.

Now let $\delta=(a+b)-q$, which is rational. Let $a'=a-\frac{\delta}{2}$, and $b'=b-\frac{\delta}{2}$. Then $a'\in C_x$, $b'\in C_y$, and
$$a'+b' = a+b-\delta = q.$$
Thus, $q\in C_x+C_y$, proving that $C_{x+y}\subseteq C_x+C_y$.